# How to allow user in my Database to download only his images from s3 bucket?

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, flask, amazon-cloudfront

I'm using flask as backend for REST APIs. I have a database which contains users and images information uploaded by them. All the images are stored in a S3 bucket like **"bucket_name/user_1/img1.jpg"**. I want to allow the users to download all the images that are only specific to them i.e in folder **"user_1"** and they shouldn't have access to **"user_2"** images. Also the bucket and it's contents are private.

Image table has image_path (like "bucket_name/user_1/img1.jpg") which can be accessed by flask app only. REST APIs are used by android app.

So when the user on android app fetches his image (using GET request), he should be able to download all the images. How to deliver those images?

- Using aws cloudfront and oai
- flask using boto3 generate_presigned_url()
- make the bucket contents public (which I definitely don't want)

How this android -- flask -- aws flow should work?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you can achieve this.

1. You could use pre-signed URLs, or
2. Provide temporary credentials that permit access to their folder.

**Pre-Signed URLs**

Keep all content **private**. Then, when a client (eg Android app) requires access to an object, your application should verify that they are entitled to access the object by checking the database. If they *are* permitted access, then the application should generate a **pre-signed URL** that grants time-limited access to the object.

Creating a pre-signed URL only takes a couple of lines of code and does not require a call to AWS. Thus, it is very fast to create and the application retains full control over who is permitted access to which objects.

**Temporary Credentials**

Since your users are permitted to access all content within their folder, you could [create Temporary Security Credentials](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_temp.html) using the **Security Token Service**. A policy can be assigned to these credentials that permits access to `s3://bucket_name/user_1/*`. Then, the Android app can use these credentials to directly call the AWS API to download content (or upload, or do whatever permission you have assigned).

This allows the app to directly communicate with AWS rather than having to call your servers for every object access.

If you are using federated authentication (eg trusting Facebook), you might want to [use Amazon Cognito to Get Credentials](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/getting-credentials.html).